# Multiply multiple _mm128 with single entry of _mm256

Tags: intel, sse, intrinsics, avx

I have 8 _mm128 registers and each register needs to be multiplied by a single entry of another _mm256 register.

One solution that jumps to my mind would be:

```
INPUT: __m128 a[8]; __m256 b;

__m128 tmp = _mm256_extractf128_ps(b,0);
a[0] = _mm_mul_ps(a[0],_mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0));
a[1] = _mm_mul_ps(a[1],_mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0x55));
a[2] = _mm_mul_ps(a[2],_mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0xAA));
a[3] = _mm_mul_ps(a[3],_mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0xFF));
tmp = _mm256_extractf128_ps(b,1);
a[4] = _mm_mul_ps(a[4],_mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0));
a[5] = _mm_mul_ps(a[5],_mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0x55));
a[6] = _mm_mul_ps(a[6],_mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0xAA));
a[7] = _mm_mul_ps(a[7],_mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0xFF));
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: To get the lower 128 bits of `b` you don't need to extract, you can just use a cast which does not actually create any code `tmp = __mm256_castps128_ps256(b)`.  It just makes the compiler happy.  To get the upper 128 bits you still need to extract as you did.

Answer (score 3):

I think your solution is about as good as it's going to get, except that I would use explicit variables rather than an array, so that everything stays in registers as far as possible:

```
__m128 a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7;
__m256 b;

__m128 tmp = _mm256_extractf128_ps(b,0);
a0 = _mm_mul_ps(a0, _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0));
a1 = _mm_mul_ps(a1, _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0x55));
a2 = _mm_mul_ps(a2, _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0xAA));
a3 = _mm_mul_ps(a3, _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0xFF));
tmp = _mm256_extractf128_ps(b,1);
a4 = _mm_mul_ps(a4, _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0));
a5 = _mm_mul_ps(a5, _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0x55));
a6 = _mm_mul_ps(a6, _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0xAA));
a7 = _mm_mul_ps(a7, _mm_shuffle_ps(tmp,tmp,0xFF));
```

Comment: Given the amount of shuffles involved, it might actually be worthwhile to try doing a store + broadcast. Not that I've tested it though.

Comment: Perhaps - but I'd expect pretty good parallelism with the shuffles and the multiplies?

Comment: Good point. I forgot that there's a port for shuffles that's separate from the FP-add and FP-mul ports.

Comment: thank you. One questions remains, what prevents the compiler from using registers when I use an array of fixed size?

Comment: Good question - I've never seen a compiler that will cache a small array in registers though - it may be something to do with aliasing or it may just be that it's a fairly rare use case that hasn't received much love from compiler-writers.